# Azure Function orchestration with event hub

Tags: azure-functions

I want to perform orchestration with multiple function with typescript, but my question is I am listening existing azure event hub and output of event I want to pass it out to another azure function. then I have to pass same data to 2rd function and so on...

Function would be following sequence.

1. Get data from Event hub which is listen the event hub with all partition this is function 0
2. Pass the event hub (function 0) data to another httptrigger function 1
3. Get function 1 data to and pass to function 2

Could you please suggest the solution on this with Azure function + typescript

Regards,
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

By using durable function to do multiple jobs parallelly. As your requirement you need to pass the function value as a req on client function which follows it will trigger the orchestration function.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
const client = df.getClient(context);
const instanceId = await client.startNew(req.params.functionName, undefined, req.body);
context.log(`Started orchestration with ID = '${instanceId}'.`);
return client.createCheckStatusResponse(context.bindingData.req, instanceId);
};
```

In orchestration function you need to call the activity function which you want to pass the output of event hub values to another function.

```
const df = require('durable-functions');
module.exports = df.orchestrator(function*(context){

// your code here
// Get input from the client that started
// get event hub values here

const Eventhub_value = context.df.getInput();

// Call Activity that fetches all lists that arent hidden, and wait for it to finish

const Fun1_op = yield context.df.callActivity("Function_1", Eventhub_value); 
const output = [];
output.push(yield context.df.callActivity("Function_2", Fun1_op));
}

// Here we could save the result to some DB if we want to
// yield context.df.callActivity('SaveItems', output);
// For this example we just log the result

context.log(JSON.stringify(output));
return context.instanceId;
});
```

In a same way you can achieve by using durable function with Typescript.

Refer the [Blog](https://www.agrenpoint.com/intro-durable/)  &  [Document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js) for more information